# how to add lxc containers to host's DNS so that getaddrinfo() can resolve them?

Tags: networking, lxc, dnsmasq

I'm running LXC containers on Ubuntu 12.04 with a 3.8 kernel.  The containers are on a host-only network, so their addresses are managed by dnsmasq.  Is there a way to configure the host so that getaddrinfo() (on the host) can resolve container names?  (I know there ways to resolve container names from the shell, but I'm specifically looking for something that works with getaddrinfo()).

Answer (score 3):

The following works on 12.04 with the 3.11 kernel.  On the host, add this to /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head:

`nameserver 10.0.3.1`

and then run this on the host to update your /etc/resolv.conf:

`sudo resolvconf -u`

After that, remove this from the container's /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/original:

`nameserver 127.0.0.1`

and then run this in the container to update its /etc/resolv.conf:

`sudo resolvconf -u`